# Getting NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA error when making ssr get calls on now

Tags: vue.js, aws-lambda, nuxt.js, vercel, cockpit-cms

I'm running a nuxt universal app on now.sh which makes an ssr get call to a https://getcockpit.com/ server somewhere else. When I open the app I get a 502 error with code "NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA".

Running it locally or deploying it as a spa instead of universal app works just fine because then the calls aren't made from lambda but from my machine I guess. My webserver running the getcockpit-cms does not receive any call from now according to it's logs so the problem doesn't seem to be on that side.

The now.sh logs really don't say much to me. The only thing I found is "Process excited before completing request" but that doesn't help me either.

```
'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     data: undefined },
  request: 
   Writable {
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: { response: [Function], error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options: 
      { protocol: 'http:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        path: '/api/singletons/get/intro',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        auth: undefined,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: '3000',
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/api/singletons/get/intro' },
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _redirects: [],
     _requestBodyLength: 0,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'GET /api/singletons/get/intro HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nx-real-ip: 5.149.20.127\r\nsec-fetch-user: ?1\r\nsec-fetch-site: none\r\nupgrade-insecure-requests: 1\r\ncache-control: no-cache\r\nx-now-trace: zrh1\r\nx-now-deployment-url: BLURRED-NOW-DEPLOYMENT-URL\r\nx-zeit-co-forwarded-for: 5.149.20.127\r\naccept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7\r\nx-forwarded-proto: https\r\nsec-fetch-mode: navigate\r\nx-forwarded-for: 5.149.20.127\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nx-now-id: clckl-1566116017296-db7c5240b52c\r\npragma: no-cache\r\nx-forwarded-host: BLURRED-NOW-DEPLOYMENT-URL\r\nconnection: close\r\nAuthorization: Bearer BLURRED-API-KEY\r\nHost: localhost:3000\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/singletons/get/intro',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Circular],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/singletons/get/intro' },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function] }
END RequestId: 5153a263-0ac9-4bf5-9c7d-4422783386ba
REPORT RequestId: 5153a263-0ac9-4bf5-9c7d-4422783386ba  Duration: 234.13 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 97 MB  
RequestId: 5153a263-0ac9-4bf5-9c7d-4422783386ba Process exited before completing request


START RequestId: f32bcba9-aea6-46d0-9269-c0544a211fff Version: $LATEST
2019-08-18T08:13:39.117Z    f32bcba9-aea6-46d0-9269-c0544a211fff    λ Cold start took: 339.379719ms
END RequestId: f32bcba9-aea6-46d0-9269-c0544a211fff
REPORT RequestId: f32bcba9-aea6-46d0-9269-c0544a211fff  Duration: 115.83 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 53 MB
```

I would expect now.sh or rather lambda to make the call and ssr my app.

Comment: Having the exact same problem, though I'm using Zeit Now lambdas I'm getting the same error message. Will let you know if I find out more. The frustrating part is that this error happens sometimes, usually after long periods of inactivity on the site.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but sometimes I find that my app (by running now dev) runs out of memory / I'm occasionally getting the error message "pool is draining and cannot accept work" so those might be related, on my end. So maybe Zeit Now runs out of memory? It doesn't seem to report any high amounts of memory or time usage though.